# Assigning location values based on date and time of a second data set

Tags: r, dataframe, gis, interpolation, regularized

I have 2 data frames: 1 is a sequence of GPS locations with associated date-times (POSIXct)

```
GPS <- data.frame(Lat=c(58.65209, 58.65183, 58.65142, 58.65129, 58.65126, 58.65124, 58.65122, 58.65119, 58.65117, 58.65115),
                  Lon=c(-3.178559, -3.177934, -3.177277, -3.177536, -3.177494, -3.177713, -3.177806, -3.177899, -3.177991, -3.178084), 
                  datetime=c("2016-10-01 16:23:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:31:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:39:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:47:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:55:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 17:03:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 17:11:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 17:19:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 17:27:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 17:35:59 GMT"))

GPS$datetime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(GPS$datetime))
```

and another is a sequence of depths with associated date-times (POSIXct).

```
DEPTH <- data.frame(Depth=c(0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 1.5, 1.7, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.3, 1.7, 2.0, 2.6, 2.2, 2.1, 3.4, 3.3), 
                    datetime=c("2016-10-01 16:22:56 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:23:06 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:23:16 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:23:59 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:24:52 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:25:24 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:32:40 GMT", "2016-10-01 16:32:51 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:45:30 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:45:40 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:46:54 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:47:04 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:47:14 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:47:25 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:51:03 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:51:14 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:51:24 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:54:11 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:54:21 GMT", "2016-10-01 18:54:32 GMT"))

DEPTH$datetime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(DEPTH$datetime))
```

For each depth location I want to assign a location (latitude and longitude) based on when the interpolated track from the location data frame suggests it should be i.e. if the locations go from point A to point B at which point along that line does the depth data lie, assuming a uniform speed between points, given it's date-time.

the final product would be 2 vectors in the data-frame which assign each depth value with a latitude and a longitude.

Thank you.

Comment: @Sotos The expected output is 2 extra vectors in the depth data frame with a location for each depth value. I have updated the question to qualify this. I Haven't tried anything yet as my experience in using spatial tools like this is limited.

Comment: Still very unclear (to me at least)

Comment: @Sotos apologies for seeming unclear - the answer from below was exactly what I was after. For future reference so my questions are more approachable how could I improve the wording? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming constant velocity (uniform speed **and** constant direction) between successive *way-points* in the `GPS` data, we can perform linear interpolation separately for `Lat` and `Lon` using `approx` from `stats`:

```
DEPTH$Lat <- approx(x=GPS$datetime, y=GPS$Lat, xout=DEPTH$datetime, method="linear")$y
DEPTH$Lon <- approx(x=GPS$datetime, y=GPS$Lon, xout=DEPTH$datetime, method="linear")$y
```

In this usage, interpolated values for `datetime` in `DEPTH` outside of the range of `datetime` in `GPS` are assigned `NA`. See `?approx` for other ways to dealing with interpolating outside the range of the input.

Using your data, the result is:

```
print(DEPTH)
##   Depth            datetime      Lat       Lon
##1    0.0 2016-10-01 16:22:56       NA        NA
##2    0.1 2016-10-01 16:23:06       NA        NA
##3    0.0 2016-10-01 16:23:16       NA        NA
##4    0.0 2016-10-01 16:23:59 58.65209 -3.178559
##5    0.1 2016-10-01 16:24:52 58.65206 -3.178490
##6    1.5 2016-10-01 16:25:24 58.65204 -3.178448
##7    1.7 2016-10-01 16:32:40 58.65179 -3.177878
##8    1.7 2016-10-01 16:32:51 58.65179 -3.177863
##9    1.4 2016-10-01 18:45:30       NA        NA
##10   1.5 2016-10-01 18:45:40       NA        NA
##11   1.8 2016-10-01 18:46:54       NA        NA
##12   2.1 2016-10-01 18:47:04       NA        NA
##13   2.3 2016-10-01 18:47:14       NA        NA
##14   1.7 2016-10-01 18:47:25       NA        NA
##15   2.0 2016-10-01 18:51:03       NA        NA
##16   2.6 2016-10-01 18:51:14       NA        NA
##17   2.2 2016-10-01 18:51:24       NA        NA
##18   2.1 2016-10-01 18:54:11       NA        NA
##19   3.4 2016-10-01 18:54:21       NA        NA
##20   3.3 2016-10-01 18:54:32       NA        NA
```

Comment: Bingo, exactly what I was after. Thank you, @aichao.